# How to link my aws cloudformation and my DNS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

### Hi, here is my problem,

I've been trying to switch from Hostgator hosting to AWS with wp template in cloud formation.
I have created a stack in cloudformation, then I asossiated an elastic IP to the EC2 instance. After that I changed the nameservers in GoDaddy to NS73.DOMAINCONTROL.COM and created new A record pointing to the elastic ip. 2 days have passed since I've made the changes and my blog home page still shows GoDaddy's page.
Please help me find what have I done wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two A records. The first points at GoDaddy, the second points at Amazon.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
greatapp101.com.    576 IN  A   184.168.221.47
greatapp101.com.    576 IN  A   54.149.48.24
```

Most DNS systems permit multiple A records (called "round-robin DNS"). Find the first record and delete it.

Comment: Now when I remember, I havent finished installing wp in the stack Step 6 from the [Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html) guide because it wanted me to make a new registration for wp so i did what i did. I am unable to do it now because it opens a time out error page.